# Proof for planar embeddings

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that any planar embedding of a simple connected planar graph contains a vertex of degree at most $3$ or a face of degree at most $3$.

Can someone help me with this please? Thank you!

Comment: It would be better if you post some of your thoughts or your work, that way people would be more willing to help ...

Comment: I am stuck on this problem, and I don't really know what to do :\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  If every face has degree $4$ or more, then we can use Euler's polyhedron formula to show that $e \leq 2v - 4$. What does that imply about the degrees in the graph?

Comment: Sorry but I still don't really know how to use that to prove this problem, can you give me some tips on how to do this?

Comment: The handshaking lemma says that the sum of the degrees is twice the number of edges...

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I forgot about that. so that means that the total number of degree is $≤ v − 2$. How will this help me with proving this?

Comment: Oh, can I say something like. since the number of degrees $≤$ vertices - 2, therefore there can't be any vertices of degree 3 or more? Since if there is, then the formula can't be true.

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it now. Thank you!